# Probability distribution function from density function

Tags: distributions

I need to get probability distribution function from density function:

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\alpha x_m^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}} &x\geq x_m, \\
0 & x<x_m.\end{cases}$$

Comment: If this is a self-study question then please add that tag and read its wiki http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why was this edit approved?

Comment: @gung if it was me and I remember correctly I suspect the answer is "by mistake". I think I saw it as an attempt by the OP to clarify the question.

Comment: [and bad mistakes, I've made a few](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04854XqcfCY) myself, @mdewey.

Comment: @surligneur, integrate it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the nice, simple homework problem.

My students will appreciate the opportunity to find $F(q)$ by integrating the function from $x_m$ to $q$.  And, of course, defining the range of the parameter $\alpha$ for which the result makes sense.  Which, of course, leads to conditions on the existence of the usual moments of $X$.